# Generate apk using ANT in ubuntu Terminal

Tags: android, ubuntu, ant, terminal

I am trying to generate a dynamic APK using Ant through the terminal. I couldn't find 'build.XML' in my system. I tried this command,
`ant debug` in Terminal.

but i got error like this:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I tried this command `android update project -t android-10 -p`, but
I got error like this:
`android: command not found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `android` tool has been added to your `PATH`.

For example, you can do this temporarily:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/tools
```

Assuming that the Android SDK Tools are installed at `/path/to/android-sdk/tools`.

Comment: I am using Android studio. I dont know path  /android-SDK/tools